# Assert doesn't catch errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js, assert

I have this function:

```js
await sendTx(newProxyAddr, false, 'initialize', [0, nullAddr]);
```

...that produces this error:

```
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Initializable: contract is already initialized'
```

But when I try to catch the error on a test using:

```js
assert.throws(async () => {
   await sendTx(newProxyAddr, false, 'initialize', [0, nullAddr]);
}, Error, 'Thrown');
```

..., it tells me:

```
AssertionError: expected [Function] to throw an error
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Node.js [`assert.rejects(asyncFn[, error][, message])`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v14.x/api/assert.html#assert_assert_rejects_asyncfn_error_message) API for async function or JS promise.

`assert.throws` calls `getActual(promiseFn)` function which will NOT `await` the `promiseFn`, see [v14.19.3/lib/assert.js#L899](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v14.19.3/lib/assert.js#L899)

`assert.rejects` calls `await waitForActual(promiseFn)` will await the `promiseFn`, see [v14.19.3/lib/assert.js#L909](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v14.19.3/lib/assert.js#L909)

E.g.

```js
const assert = require('assert');

async function sendTx() {
  throw new Error('error happens');
}

(async () => {
  await assert.rejects(
    async () => {
      await sendTx();
    },
    {
      name: 'Error',
      message: 'error happens',
    },
  );
})();
```